# Windows 7 Keyboard Language reverting back " `` "

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language, input-languages, input

I am having issues with a user who wishes to use "*Spanish (Spain-International)*". However, whenever he reboots he is unable to use the tilde (`) on vowels.

He would normaly press:

<kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = é

In his case

<kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = `e

I checked his Regional and Language Settings and compared them to mine as we are in the same environment and network. They were the same.

Default input Language: "*Spanish (Spain-International)*"

Keyboard: "*Spanish (Spain-International)*" ONLY

I then changed the default and keyboard language to "*Spanish (Spanish-Traditional)*" and remove "*Spanish (Spanish-International)*". This resolves the issue until user logs off and on again. Once logged on again, I need to change the language again, but this time to "*Spanish (Spain-International)*" and remove Traditional. Again, user can type é/è without any issues until he reboots.

I have changed the preloaded keyboard in the Registry for that machine, but issue persists.

I would appreciate any ideas as I have scoured the web and tried checking if other applications might be changing the settings or if there is a registry value that isn't correct.

Comment: Where a _Spanish (Spain-International)_ keyboard layout comes from? Compare [Windows Keyboard Layouts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts).

Comment: What is the default OS language (that of the installer)? I wonder why you have only one keyboard layout in the Settings list. I think it should be one you want on boot above and the OS default or others below that.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! I have checked layouts and both SpainInt & SpainTrad are the same, at least when it comes to image. 
The default language is English US, however, when the issue occurs, the keys are still Spanish, as per the "Ñ" and "Ç".

Comment: Could you add the following screenshots from the Regions and Languages control panel? Text Services and Input Languages (in Keyboards and Languages tab), and the Administrative tab.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue here immediately, you mentioned "I then changed the default and keyboard language to "Spanish (Spanish-Traditional)" and remove "Spanish (Spanish-International)". This resolves the issue until user logs off and on again.".

- To fix it, go back to control panel and on the Region and Language, go to "Administrative", then you can read there "Welcome screen and new user accounts" click the button "Copy Settings" might prompt you to login as admin. Then copy current settings to welcome screen and new user accounts "Click the tickbox" then click OK.

This will solve the issue :)

Comment: Hi, i didn't find a solution to this. I ended up building a new machine and new user roaming profile. Thank you